# Translate to TypeScript

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, websocket, socket.io

I'm trying to send messages in WebSocket with TypeScript. By staying this in my console, it works:

```
socket.on('displayHello', function(data) {
    $.pnotify({
        title: "Hello",
        text:  data.from + " te dis bonjour " + data.to,
        type:  "info"
    });
});
```

I want to translate it into TypeScript :

```
public onMessage(): Observable<any> {
  return new Observable(observer => {
    this.socket.on('displayHello', (data) => {

      observer.next(data);
    });
  });
}
```

I do not see how to do with the pnotify parameter because it is not recognized by TypeScript.

When I try this :

```
public onMessage(): Observable<any> {
return new Observable(observer => {
  this.socket.on('displayHello', (data) => {
    observer.next(data);
    $.pnotify({
      title: 'Hello',
      text:  data.from + ' te dis bonjour ' + data.to,
      type:  'info'
    });
  });
});
}
```

I have this error :

```
TS2339:Property 'pnotify' does not exist on type '(search: string) => ElementFinder'
```

Comment: It should be working anyways, except you're running `tsc` with the option `--noEmitOnError=true`. However, for actually solving your problem see the answer below.

Comment: @PascalBayer
Thanks for your answer, but after downloading the package with npm, I have to add something to my program? Because that does not change my problem. 'pnotify' is still not recognized

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you face could be solved by installing the type definition for `pnotify`.

Depending if you're using npm or yarn you need to perform `npm install --save-dev @types/jquery.pnotify` or `yarn add --dev @types/jquery.pnotify`.

Also make sure that you're using a recent version of TypeScript that does automatically locate type definitions within the `@types/`-Folder

Comment: After downloading the package with npm, I have to add something to my program?
Because that does not change my problem. 'pnotify' is still not recognized

Comment: @Floriane Could you outline the setup of your project?